# Python - convert list of string to float - square braces and decimal point causing problems

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I have a text file that contains a smaller dataset(taken from csv file) like so -

```
2020-05-24T10:44:37.613168#[ 0.          0.         -0.06210425  0.        ]
2020-05-24T10:44:37.302214#[1. 1. 0. 0.]
2020-05-24T10:44:36.192222#[0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Then read from it using

```
data = f.readlines()
for row in data:
    img_id, label = row.strip("\n").split("#")
```

where in label is a string list which looks like

```
[ 0.          0.         -0.24604772  0.        ]
[ 0.          0.         -0.24604772  0.        ]
[1. 1. 0. 0.]
```

I'd like to convert each string element to float. However, the square brace `[]` and decimal `.` preventing me from converting.

**Tried so far -**

1. Removing `[]` so - `label = label[1:-1]` but I would need them as an array later. 
   Then doing this `print([list(map(float, i.split())) for i in label])` resulted in error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'`
2. Using `ast.literal_eval`.`label = ast.literal_eval(row.strip("\n").split("#"))`. Getting `ValueError: malformed node or string: ['2020-05-24T10:57:52.882241 [0. 0. 0. 0.]']`

**Referred**

[Need to read string into a float array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222702/need-to-read-string-into-a-float-array)

[Cannot convert list of strings to list of floats in python using float()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953188/cannot-convert-list-of-strings-to-list-of-floats-in-python-using-float)

[How do you convert a list of strings to a list of floats using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51844300/how-do-you-convert-a-list-of-strings-to-a-list-of-floats-using-python)

[Convert list of strings to numpy array of floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56642038/convert-list-of-strings-to-numpy-array-of-floats)

[When to use ast.literal_eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552950/when-to-use-ast-literal-eval)

So,

1. What else should I try in order to convert them to float array which is iterable? Or what am I doing wrong? Should I have to remove the square braces?
2. If I can make things much easier, how can I store the data in txt file? Is CSV better than txt in this case?
3. I need to extend this logic to 110,000 entries. Will any of steps cause problems then?

Thank you. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Please help.

Comment: Hello!
1. Why there are so many spaces in some lines?
2. Which float-values do you mean? -0.24604772 is a float, but "1." is not

Comment: This the `str` display of an array.  It's not designed for recreating an array.  Since it's missing the commas it can't be parsed as a list.  Use string methods to clean it up one or the other.  `numpy` isn't going to help you.

Comment: @ProgrammerJonas I mean if a float number is present, its precision width is taken. 1. row doesn't have a larger float number. So it is normal spaced. The thing is I stored it like that in the first place into txt file.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks. I will consider this. After seeing the solutions, I think it is better not to store it as numpy array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each line, trim off the first and last char with `line[1:-1]`, split by whitespace with `.split()`, and parse each float with `float()`.

```py
line = "[ 0.          0.         -0.24604772  0.        ]"
floats = [float(item) for item in line[1:-1].split()]

print(floats)
>>> [0.0, 0.0, -0.24604772, 0.0]
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I exclude the delimiter `#` while saving to the txt file and leave it as whitespace between timestamp and the list. How can export the data into list variables?

Answer (score 1):

```py
    for row in data:
        img_id, label = row.strip("\n").split("#")
        # >>>[ 0.          0.         -0.24604772  0.        ]

        label = label[1:-1] # Cuts the first and last letter
        # >>> 0.          0.         -0.24604772  0.   

        label = label.strip() # Remove all spaces before and after label
        # >>>0.          0.         -0.24604772  0.

        labelElements = label.split() # Cuts the string on every space(s)
        # >>>["0.", "0.", "-0.24604772", "0."]

        labelFloats = []
        for L in labelElements:
            labelFloats.append(float(L)) # for example: "1." -> 1.0
```

By the way:
The variable [label] does not have a list of lines (You called it a "string list"), its one line:

```
# label = [ 0.          0.         -0.24604772  0.        ]
```

Comment: My bad. I didn't know the right term to call it. I learned something new now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think given your case, I think I would go with regular expressions to extract the desired numbers. I would do something as follows:

```
import re


f = open('your_file.txt')
lines = f.read().splitlines()
f.close()
floats = []
for line in lines:
    img_id, label = line.split("#")
    floats.append([*map(float, re.findall('-?[\d]+\.?[\d]*', label))])
```

Printing `floats` outputs:

```
[[0.0, 0.0, -0.06210425, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```